# What is the relationship between the different grails 3 css files?

Tags: css, grails

- What is the relationship between the different CSS files in a Grails 3 app.?

errors.css

main.css

grails.css

application.css

mobile.css

bootstrap.css

- Which files are mandatory?
- Which CSS rules are mandatory?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: None of them are mandatory. It is just provided "template" structure of how you could structure your css.

Comment: And what do you mean by relationship between files? Like - which one is higher in hierarchy? The one that's added to the gsp later. If you have doubts, just add different colors to the same object and see which one compiles last.